# Corda flow acceptance from other party, can other party manually signs the transaction?

Tags: corda

Link that I referred is:

[Corda: User interaction for verifying the transaction request received from the initiator node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45845262/corda-user-interaction-for-verifying-the-transaction-request-received-from-the)

In this case, the propose flow should be signed by both parties, right?
And same way the Accept/Reject should be signed by Initator and Reciever ?

Can anyone please let me know how to retrieve the state using an attribute other than linear id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set of public keys that is required to sign a transaction is given by the union of all the public keys listed on all the commands in the transaction.

For querying a state by custom attributes, see https://docs.corda.net/api-vault-query.html. You need to create a `VaultCustomQueryCriteria`, which requires your state to implement the `QueryableState` interface.

Comment: Ok..So within one transaction can we have multple commands ?My understanding was , for one transaction ,there is one flow and one corresponding command. Is there any example that shows one transaction and multiple commands?

Comment: Here is an example: https://github.com/corda/obligation-cordapp/blob/release-V3/kotlin-source/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/examples/obligation/flows/SettleObligation.kt. This transaction has an obligation settlement command for the obligation, and a cash transfer command for the cash (the cash command is added automatically as part of `Cash.generateSpend`).